# Custom Filter Factory which extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory not getting called on doing redirect to /login/oauth2/code/azure

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I have an application where the redirect uri is configured as /api/login/oauth.

I am trying to capture the request using webflux Get endpoint and redirect it to /login/oauth2/code/azure endpoint.

Though, the request is getting captured its not calling the custom GatewayFilterFactory which we have configured.

The same CustomGatewayFilterFactory gets called if the redirect uri of an application is configured as /login/oauth2/code/azure. There is no predicate configuration in the application.yml.

This is required as we have recently migrated to Spring Cloud Gateway.

I have tried adding couple of predicates to capture the request of /api/login/oauth and redirect it to /login/oauth2/code/azure but that's some how is not helping.

Can someone suggest an ideal way to do this?